# How to change the start menu for restricted user on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, active-directory

I am the administrator of my network & I have a restricted user on the network. I noticed that the default start menu for a restricted user leaves off 99% of shortcuts that could actually be useful; for example downloads.

How can I—as an administrator—change that user’s start menu items via the task bar and start menu program in the control panel which is of course blocked out on that persons own account?

If it makes any difference my users are managed by Active Directory on a Windows 2003 server.

Comment: Running control panel as admin as shown here: http://superuser.com/questions/663308/how-do-i-run-control-panel-administrator does not work. It seems to leave out the desired pogram, manybe since it is running in invisible admin space

Comment: What have you researched or tried so far? Have you looked at [Group Policies](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/group-policy-management-for-it-pros)?

Comment: @CharlieRB I am not natively a Windows AD Administrator, I have some working knowledge, but when it comes to specific group policies I am a little lost.

Comment: @CharlieRB It should also be mentioned that this isn't about raising the users group policy to be able to do this but for me, as an adminstrator, to do this and then for that user to continue without further interferrance.

Comment: This isn't the place to learn how to administer user policies. You are going to have to do some research. Honestly, this question is off-topic because it has to do with a corporate network. Super User is for personal computing and home networks.

Comment: Is there a reason you can not log on as administrator, do what you need, then log off?

Comment: @CharlieRB I thought that but then I can only think of how to change my own settings, not the other users

Comment: @CharlieRB I have done research, however, you mentioning group policy has allowed to continue another avenue of investigation which did not turn up on Google when searching around, which came to this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee617162%28v=ws.10%29.aspx however, it mentions that these settings are new to Widnows 7 which makes me think they would not be available on Server 2003.

Comment: @CharlieRB if this question is off-topic for that reason then you should prolly revise the sites use of the http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/active-directory tag and in fact almost every permisssion question on this site

Comment: Looking at it again, your question doesn't actually state "Company Network" or "at my company", so I retract my off-topic statement. As far as the tag, there are lots of people who run servers on private networks. It is outlined in the **[Help Center](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)**, but that doesn't stop people from asking. In the question, wording is everything. :-)